# Warning in install.packages : cannot remove prior installation of package ‘data.table’

Tags: r, data.table

I tried to install package data.table in R. This error showed up. Could anyone resolve this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I assume you're on Windows. You may have data.table loaded into your session already; on Windows, dlls that are part of a package can't be unloaded until R shuts down. So restart R and then try running `install.packages` again.

Comment: Restarted R and the problem persists

Comment: I have found that it sometimes help to close out of a project and then try again.

Comment: My experience: 1. close all projects using R, including RStudio projects; 2. restart R and then run install.packages("data.table") again.

Comment: Ensure that the R session is the only open session often helps even if you have not loaded the library (including processes like R language server in vscode)

Answer (score 3):

Try running R with admin access (sudo in Linux, or for Windows, right click and choose "Run as Administrator"). I had the same problem when running R from PowerShell in Windows, and this fixed it.

Comment: Did not work for me.