# Addressing the "cannot remove prior installation of package" error when updating multiple packages at once

Tags: r, package-management

This is a problem that comes up repeatedly, e.g.

- [Error in install.packages : cannot remove prior installation of package ‘DBI’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922418/error-in-install-packages-cannot-remove-prior-installation-of-package-dbi)
- [Warning in install.packages : cannot remove prior installation of package ‘data.table’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918543/warning-in-install-packages-cannot-remove-prior-installation-of-package-data)
- [Unable to install package forecast in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689061/unable-to-install-package-forecast-in-r)
- [Install error of package plyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240000/install-error-of-package-plyrof-islr)
- [Unable to install package zoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012471/unable-to-install-package-zoo)

I have come across this issue multiple times. Most annoying is when it occurs with a bunch of packages; e.g. I do something like

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```

and get a number of these errors. The error is misleading though, because R tends to **actually remove** the old package version---but then doesn't install the new version. Once this happens, you can't fix it with `update.packages`; you have to reinstall it from scratch.

The most frustrating aspect of this problem is that it often occurs when installing *dependencies*, so e.g. I might successfully update `dplyr`, but in the process `Rcpp` is removed. Now I can't load `dplyr` because `Rcpp` is missing, so I need to reinstall `Rcpp`.

My current workaround (when the number of uninstalled packages is large) is to close all of my R sessions, open a new one with the base R GUI (i.e. not RStudio or RTVS) and do

```
lapply(dir(.libPaths()), install.packages)
```

which reinstalls my entire library. This is overkill.

**Is there a better way to check which folders in `.libPaths()` actually contain packages, so that I only reinstall the missing packages?**

Alternatively: **Is there a better way to check for missing package depedencies?**

Comment: I see my question has been downvoted a couple of times. If you can explain why the question is considered poor-quality, I would be happy to improve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One strategy is to do

```
setdiff(dir(.libPaths()), .packages(all = TRUE))
```

To get a list of directories in the library that don't seem to actually contain packages. Now I have a much smaller list of packages to reinstall.

I'm not sure if it's foolproof, but it's better than reinstalling my entire library.